# SQL How to group data together

Tags: sql

[image: Table with unsorted data]

The Table with unsorted data shows the data I'm getting right now. What I need to do is group the usernames together. So it will look like the picture "Table with sorted data". Please let me know if my question is unclear. I'm not very good at explaining things.

[image: Table with sorted data]

Comment: Show what your current query looks like. Should by able to d an: ORDER BY UserName,  isNull(loggedOn, somedate)

Comment: Looking at your data - a user can log on multiple times before logging off once. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct @Nicarus

Comment: So, how do you want to handle those log in times that are between the first log in and the log off time?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it appears that a user can login multiple times without logging out. The below query will grab the next soonest logout time for each user after each login. Without a session id, there doesn't appear to be any way to guarantee which logout time is associated to each login.

```
Select UserName, 
    LoggedOn, 
    (select min(LoggedOut) from dbo.MyTable T1 where T.UserName = T1.UserName and T.LoggedOn <= T1.LoggedOut)
from dbo.MyTable T
where LoggedOn is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

In Sql data always shows without group but the app or the report use this repeated field for group it just like you like to do.

Comment: [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) can help you write answers that will be upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you what you're looking for i believe. if you don't care about the order, other than grouping the Username together you can take away the ", LoggedOn" following the Order by clause. You can also put other paramaters behind the first Order by field and it will order your result set first by Username, then by Logged on, then by x, then by y..

Hope this helps.

```
select UserName, LoggedOn, LoggedOut 
from dbo.Table
Order by Username, LoggedOn
```